# How to create SSRS Forms?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I've an SSRS report that requires some data input at the runtime, i.e. most of the data on the report comes from SQL Server, however, there are some fields that needs to be input by the user at the run time. Data input in these fields will only be printed on the report and will not be saved in the database.

How can this be achieved in SSRS? Is there a way to create a custom form in SSRS?

Comment: SSRS is not intended to be a tool to create forms and store data to the datasource. You can create some kind of form by using parameters but parameters are used to filter the data used in the report. If you require a form implementation you should use some web framework to do that.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta Thank you for your reply. Can you please elaborate on the web framework. Also, just to add more info, the data input by the user is not going to be stored back to the database.

Comment: You can create a parameter that lets the user type or select a value, then you can show/print that value in the report by using something like this:  `=Parameters!ParameterName.Value`.